# Rep indicator doesn't reflect rep changes in android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, achievements-dialog

Even if I have some upvotes on my posts, it looks the same always:

[image]

(I expect to see something like +[some rep], like on the site)

However when I click it, I can see my new rep changes highlighted.

Could the highlighting of rep indicator be implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bug. Probably more of a feature request.