# Check reputation on Android watch

Tags: feature-request, android-app

This is related to [Make notifications from the Stack Exchange app compatible with smart watches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266601/279167).

I just got an Android watch and basically the only reason I have left to check my phone is to see if my reputation changed. I do receive notifications of comments and answers to my questions on the watch. Is it possible/could it be possible to check reputation on a watch?

Comment: The ordinary app does not show reputation changes, never did, it's not relevant if it's on a watch, phone, or anything else running android.

Comment: @Shadow This is not a duplicate. I'm not asking for notification of reputation changes, I just want to be able to check it. It's okay if I have to touch something to do that. Like the reputation widget on the phone.

Comment: Fair enough. But if you refer to the app installed on a watch, this is still a duplicate, of this one instead: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238517/rep-indicator-doesnt-reflect-rep-changes-in-android-app?noredirect=1

Comment: @Shadow did you link the wrong question?

Comment: No. In the app we have that indicator, but it never show the reputation change. The feature request I linked to is asking to have it show the reputation change, which is what you ask for. Unless I got something wrong myself?

Comment: @Shadow I can track the change myself. It would be fine to just somehow see the number on the watch, either the complete number or the change, so I don't have to go to my phone

Comment: And the app as-is can't run on a smart watch?

Comment: @Shadow Not the Samsung Gear 2, as far as I can tell.